# I keep getting an error when trying to add share button to iPad code

Tags: objective-c, uipopovercontroller

I keep getting the popovercontroller error when calling code, here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)sharePost:(id)sender {
    NSArray *activityItems;
    NSInteger tid = ((UIControl *) sender).tag;

    if ([catName isEqualToString:@"All"])
    {
        //UIImage *snapshotImage = [self imageFromView:self.view];
        activityItems = @[[self.titleArray objectAtIndex:tid],[self.linkArray objectAtIndex:tid],[self.imageArray objectAtIndex:tid]];
    }
    else
    {
        activityItems = @[[self.titleCatArray objectAtIndex:tid],[self.linkCatArray objectAtIndex:tid],[self.imageCatArray objectAtIndex:tid]];
    }

    UIActivityViewController *activityController =

    [[UIActivityViewController alloc]

     initWithActivityItems:activityItems

     applicationActivities:nil];

    [self presentViewController:activityController         
                       animated:YES completion:nil];        
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

I want to get it working on iPad and I have looked at everything online but cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation to UIActivityViewController:

> On iPad, you must present the view controller in a popover. On iPhone and iPod touch, you must present it modally.

Try:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:activityController];
    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:[sender bounds]
                             inView:sender        
           permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny        
                           animated:YES];
    self.popover = popover;
} else {
    [self presentViewController:activityController
                       animated:YES
                     completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Now it is coming up with warnings:

Comment: Warning: Use of undeclared identifier for didReceiveMemoryWarning after adding this

Comment: Do you have a `}` for the end of `sharePost:` after the `}` to end the `else`-clause?